# How to search in the forge viewer model efficiently using double quotes?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/search-method-performance) blog post Augusto showed that if I use double quotes like below

```js
viewer.search('"GRIDPL 2 of GRIDFACES 1 of REFGRD /144CAGRIDS_E3D/WET-END"', (ids)=>{console.log(ids)}, ['Name']);
```

search is very fast. Yes, that's true. But when the attribute name is stored in a variable how can I use double quote?
I've tried several ways but no luck -

```js
let s = "GRIDPL 2 of GRIDFACES 1 of REFGRD /144CAGRIDS_E3D/WET-END";
viewer.search('\'' + s + '\'', (ids)=>{console.log(ids)}, ['Name']) //[]
viewer.search('\'"' + s + '"\'', (ids)=>{console.log(ids)}, ['Name']) //[]
viewer.search(`'"${s}"'`, (ids)=>{console.log(ids)}, ['Name']) //[]
```

All the above gives empty array, like bellow image -
[image]

Could you please help?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the last variant, and that's what you'd need:

```
viewer.search(`"${s}"`, (ids)=>{console.log(ids)}, ['Name'])
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you very much! @Adam